Warning File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to disable file ignore
I run the command npx eslint path/file --fix --no-ignore
This is what I get:
path/file
 0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to disable file ignore settings or use "--no-warn-ignored" to suppress this warning

This is what I get what I add --debug:
npx eslint file/path --fix --no-ignore --debug
eslint:cli CLI args: [ 'file/path', '--fix', '--no-ignore', '--debug' ] +0ms
eslint:cli Using flat config? true +4ms
eslint:cli Running on files +6ms
eslint:eslint Using file patterns: file/path +0ms
eslint:eslint Searching for eslint.config.js +0ms
eslint:eslint Loading config from path-to-eslint.config.js +7ms
eslint:eslint Config file URL is file:///path-to-eslint.config.js +1ms
eslint:eslint Deleting cache file at path-to-eslintcache +31ms
eslint:eslint 1 files found in: 7ms +7ms
eslint:cli Fix mode enabled - applying fixes +50ms

path/file
  0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use "--no-ignore" to disable file ignore settings or use "--no-warn-ignored" to suppress this warning

I don't have a .eslintignore file

I just did npm install and the error went away
